# Vertically align <a> embedded in <h2>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `<a>` tag embedded in an `<h2>` tag as shown in http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpjZaJ. The problem I'm having is that the text of the hyperlink (styled as a button with Bootstrap) is lower than the `<h2>` text, ie: they're not vertically aligned. I've found that I can better align them by setting the padding of the hyperlink to 0px but that doesn't very good and seems a little hacky. I'm wondering if there's a better way to vertically center the hyperlink.

Comment: Please paste the code to the question also. A codepen link alone is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example `padding-top` was set to 0 and the text did align. I assume you want to keep the padding and still have the text aligned?

Simply set `vertical-align: initial` on the button (it's set to `middle`) and it looks good in Chrome: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvKLRw

```
.jumbotron h2 a {
    font-size: inherit;
    vertical-align: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make the link `inline-block` then vertically align it `baseline`

```css
.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
}
.jumbotron h2 a {
  font-size: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
span {
  margin-left: -100px;
}
.jumbotron h2 {
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h2><a class="btn btn-info" href="#contact">Contact Us</a> <span>to get your free estimate today.</span></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added a span and moved it over so you can see the alignment.

Comment: Button looks weird without padding though.

Comment: I took the zero padding off (I only left it on because it was in the original  code)...and it still works...check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is vertically center the hyperlink,try to add
`padding-bottom: 0px;` in class `.jumbotron h2 a` 
like this

```
    .jumbotron h2 a {
  font-size: inherit;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I believe he wants to keep the button padding intact.